# How to use in Tableau, excel averageif function

Tags: tableau-api, data-science, data-analysis, bi-tool

**Create a function that does excatly what averageif function does in Microsoft Excel**

Even if some workarounds can be done to replicate the function, they don't work in all cases (e.g. it is not possible to replicate it "dynamically" like when dragging dow in excel to change the reference value on each row)

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

For example,

AVG(if [Value] >42 then [Value] end)